# cakephp database table not found error after copied to local

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i am using cakephp 1.3 ...it was working like charm in server ,i copied it to local and executed it....after that it shows a wierd error .It says "Missing Database Table

Error: Database table inboxes for model Inbox was not found.

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_table.ctp
"
things i did after copying to local:
i used same DB with different name (yes..i changed in database.php too)

But there exist table "inbox"
I tried these ways:
1.removed inbox model and controller--nothing hapened
2.removed cache file from app/tmp/cache/models ---nothing happened
3.disabled caching from core.php

when i used another table with same name as in server its working
But nothing seems to be working after i used another database name as i am using that db name for another app ....can anyone help me on this...whats really happening with this.,its urgent..thanks in advance...

Comment: Could this just be a naming issue? The error says its looking for a table called 'inboxes' but you mentioned that the table was called 'inbox' ?

Comment: that was typing mistake....naming conventions are done correctly...if its naming problem that should hide when its controller and models are deleted..right??but nothing happened..sp please suggest me another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of headache i sorted it out.
Even if i was using same DB with different name,it was using different encoding .I created new db with uttf_genereal_ci encoding and imported old one into it.Now its working like charm.Thanks guys for helping me on this

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph mentioned in the comment, it may be a spelling mistake. But there could be one more reason:

On the web servers sometimes (mostly on shared hosting) you have the database name prefix. So it is possible that the real name of the database on your server is different from the database on your localhost. You can configure this in your app folder config/database.php

Best regards,
Tony.

Comment: if prefix is making problem then ,where is my table missing error if i am using same database name as server...??it should be there even if i use same database name.    In database.php i did not mention any prefix

Comment: Do you have any other controllers/models? Are they working properly (able to read their tables)? The database must exist and be referenced properly in database.php otherwise you'd be getting an error about that instead.

Comment: is there any POSSIBILITY cakephp caches OR store database name while working on my project